# What exactly does the "m" function in the formal Bloom filter specifications do?

Tags: yellow-paper, bloom-filter

Excerpt from page 6 of the yellow white paper:

[image]

I can understand the first three definitions, the fourth one is problematic. How does the `m` function actually work? Maybe I'm not too familiar with formal specification, but I'm specifically confused on the `[i,i+1]` part. Does it  take the bits at position `i` and `i+1` of the hash, sum them up and then apply modulo 2048?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following input

> ethereum yellow paper

Consider it's `Keccak-256` hash according to [this](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) website:

> 7f110dc4c0a897ea5187a67e2c3a7db3a43410df8d1754fbdf28351c7e58400f

The first three **pairs of bytes** of `Keccak-256` of an input string-

> {7,f},{f,1},{1,0}

1) {7,f}

low order 11 bits of each of the first three **pairs** of bytes calculated using [this](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ascii-text-to-binary-converter) website

> 00110111011

Its decimal equivalent calculated using [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html?x=10101001110) website is 443.
443%2048 = 443

Bloom filter will set a 443'th bit of 2048 bit sequence.

2) {f,1}

low order 11 bits of each of the first three **pairs** of bytes calculated using [this](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ascii-text-to-binary-converter) website

> 01100110001

Its decimal equivalent calculated using [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html?x=10101001110) website is 817.
817%2048 = 817

Bloom filter will set a 817'th bit of 2048 bit sequence.

3) {1,0}

> 00110001001

low order 11 bits of each of the first three **pairs** of bytes calculated using [this](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ascii-text-to-binary-converter) website

Its decimal equivalent calculated using [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html?x=10101001110) website is 393.
393%2048 = 393

Bloom filter will set a 393'th bit of 2048 bit sequence.

`[i,i+1]` denotes bytes at position `i`  and `i+1`

Hope it helps!